# Let $E$ be uncountable. Show that the set of points whose each neighborhood has uncountable points

Tags: real-analysis

Let $E$ be uncountable. Show that the set of points whose each neighborhood has uncountable points in $E$ is uncountable.

That is, let $F$ be the subset of $E$ such that for $x\in F$, each  neighborhood of $x$ has uncountable points of $E$. Show that $F$ is uncountable.

It is easy to show $F\neq \emptyset$ by contradiction. What the proof of the above result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $C$ be the family of all open intervals that have  rational end-points and that each have countable intersection with $E.$

$(\bullet)$. Observe that any $x\in \Bbb R$ belongs to $\bigcup C=\cup_{S\in C}S$ iff $x$ has a nbhd that has countable intersection with $E .$

Now $E\cap (\bigcup C)=E\cap (\cup_{S\in C} S)=\cup_{S\in C}(E\cap S)$ is countable because $C$ is countable and because $E\cap S$ is countable for each $S\in C.$

So $F=E\setminus (E\cap (\bigcup C))$ is uncountable. And  if $x\in F$ then $x\not \in \bigcup C$ so by $(\bullet)$, $no$ nbhd of $x$ has countable intersection with $E.$

Remark. Any nbhd $U$ of any $x\in F$ has uncountable intersection with $F,$ because $E\cap U$ is uncountable and $$E\cap U=(F\cap U)\cup ((E\setminus F)\cap U)=$$  $$=(F\cap U)\cup (E \cap(\bigcup C)\cap U)\subset$$ $$\subset (F\cap U)\cup (E \cap(\bigcup C)$$ but $E \cap(\bigcup C)$ is only countable.